# Error While Upgrading 12.04 LTS to 12.10

Tags: apt, upgrade

While upgrading Ubuntu via update manager, I'm getting this following error.
After this error system is reverted back to it's original version.

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/[distro]/partner/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My `sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS Precise Pangolin - Release amd64 (20130820.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/ 
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS Precise Pangolin - Release amd64 (20130820.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/ 
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS Precise Pangolin - Release amd64 (20130820.1)]/ precise main restricted 
# See help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to # newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted 

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the 
## distribution. 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted 

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any 
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.         
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal universe 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal universe 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates universe 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates universe 

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu 
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal multiverse 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal multiverse 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates multiverse 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates multiverse 

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as 
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes 
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features. 
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
```

Comment: You have something weird in your `sources.list`. Please paste it.

Comment: You might now want to upgrade to 12.10. It'll go out of production in only a couple of weeks. Then you'll have to upgrade to 13.04, then 13.10 and then 14.04. I'd rather recommend that you upgrade directly to 14.04 or do a fresh install. I don't post this as an answer, because it isn't, but it's something to think about.

Comment: I want to upgrade to 13.04, for that i'be to upgrade to 12.10 and then to 13.04 right??

Comment: 13.04 is EOL and 12.10 will become EOL soon.Rather jump directly to 14.04LTS.That's what J Schinstad says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open *System Settings* (a.k.a. Gnome Control Center), select *Software & Updates*, select tab *Other Software* and uncheck **Canonical Partners** repository.

[image]

You can also uncheck *Source Code* on the previous tab.

Run in the Terminal `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Then you can do the update procedure.

Comment: Still I'm getting the same Error..!

Comment: Then post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file as Braiam says.

Comment: And see the updated answer.

Comment: Got this message.

bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied

Comment: Use `sudo` with the command you have tried.

Comment: both 
/etc/apt/sources.list
and 
sudo /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: I'm a new user to ubuntu, Please forgive and guide me.

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list` is not the script or command. Just open it in text editor, copy it's contents and paste inside your question.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.